# Google Drive files and folders duplication

Tags: windows-7, google-drive, google-sync

Despite of slow bandwidth at my home, I managed to upload my 4GB data to Google Drive from the internet cafe. Then, I manually copied files to Google Drive folder on my home computer and started Google Drive hoping that, as those files are already uploaded, would be marked as synced. Unfortunately, it started to download all to new file/folder appending (1) to the file/folder name.

In case of dropbox, if I upload a file from other machines and put the same files/folders in the same location in my Dropbox folder, Dropbox and will just mark it as synced.

To replicate this issue:
1. Exit/pause Google Drive app.
2. Upload a file via web interface.
3. Copy same file to Google Drive folder.
4. Start Google Drive app.
5. Another new file will be downloaded appending (1) to it's filename.
6. Browse web interface , it will have two copies of files with same name.
Note:  Tried interchanging steps 2 and 3, but same issue replicated.

Can anyone suggest me what to do in order to sync my home computer with Google Drive? I am using Windows 7 and latest Google Drive app.

Comment: I also observed that local files are uploaded to the Google Drive duplicating files on the web interface as well.

Comment: You are trying to use Google Drive like Dropbox, Google Drive isn't Dropbox, its designed to be setup on a computer, and ran in the background.

Comment: Assuming your "home" computer is different from the one you used at the Internet café, how did the copies of the files get on to it? Where the timestamps changed in the process?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you're trying to use Drive for things Drive isn't designed for.  Drive doesn't sync like Dropbox does.  When you put a new file into the desktop version of Drive, it doesn't check to see if the file already exists online.  It'll simply say that there is a file of the same name within the online drive account and will force you to change the name of one of the two files.  It can make sure that two files don't have the same name, but doesn't keep track of whether or not two files have the same content or data enclosed in them.

Basically, to drive, if you put a song in the online folder from the internet cafe, then put that exact same song in the drive from your home computer, the only similarity Drive cares about is that their filenames are identical.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about this since I don't use Google Drive, but your problem may be related to timestamps. Since you copied the files to your local Google Drive folder *after* uploading them to Google Drive, they were seen as newer and were, therefore, re-uploaded.

You could try doing the same thing but first copy the files to your local folder and then upload them to Google Drive from the internet cafe. Finally, go back to your computer and launch Google Drive again, it should now see the files as synced since the local files are older than the remote files.

Alternatively, you could change the creation date of your local files and then relaunch Google Drive. You have not specified which OS you are using. On Unix like systems (including Linux and OSX) you can change the date by running this command in your Drive Folder:

```
touch *
```

If you have multiple folders and subdirectories, do this:

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
```

I don't know how to change a timestamp in Windows but I would guess there is a way.

Comment: That may not be the case as local file is uploaded duplicating on the Web and web copy is downloaded appending (1) as suffix to the file name (as one with the same name already exists).